# When i run ng serve i get @angular errors

Tags: angular

Im new in angular, but i will try to make this works..
I have install most of the things i need.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 10.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.3
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      6.2.3
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@angular/tsc-wrapped              0.5.2
@ngtools/json-schema              1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.3
@schematics/angular               0.8.3
@schematics/update                0.8.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.20.2
```

I have manage to fix most of the errors, but still got few left
when i open the localhost:4200 all i can see is Cannot GET /

ng serve

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **  13% building modules 27/28 modules 1 active /src/styles.cssUnknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 7.0.4, but postcss-import uses
6.0.23. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.

    ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
    Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css' in '/src'
        at doResolve (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:180:19)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn0 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
        at resolver.doResolve (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn0 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn0 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
        at resolver.doResolve (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn5 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:57:1)
        at resolver.doResolve (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn0 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
        at hook.callAsync (/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
        at _fn1 (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    ERROR in src/app/app-directives/simplebtn.directive.spec.ts(6,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
```

this is the src/styles.css file, I have tryed to change it, but still have the same error.

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import '../node_modules/angular2-notifier/styles/style.css';
@import "~rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.css";
@import "~nouislider/d/nouislider.min.css";

body{
    background-color: rgba(190, 208, 216, 0.9);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your global angular cli and do again ng new for latest and also check that your nodejs and npm are latest your problem should be fixed.

Comment: node --version v10.10.0
nodejs --version v8.11.3
npm --version 6.4.1

Comment: What happens if you run `npm install`?

Comment: nothing, i have tryed that many times...
i use npm install -g @angular/cli@latest so now i have 6.2.3

Comment: delete the node_modules,  run npm install, error, gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/node_modules/node-sass/build'

Comment: and this.... npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.